# EF6 Many-to-Many on Non-Key Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having trouble connecting a many-to-many relationship in EF6 using code first, then creating a pass-through association beyond that.

There are three classes: Person, Tag, and Passing.

Each Person has an optional Bib.

Each Tag has an optional Bib, not unique.

Each Passing has a required TagId.

I want to access all Passings linked to a Person by getting all Tags with the same Bib, then getting all Passings associated with each of those Tags.

I have tried using the DBModelBuilder in my DBContext class but can't get it to work properly, and EF6 seems to try to generate an intermediate table anyways, which seems unnecessary.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Bib { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Passing> Passings
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public string Bib { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Passing> Passings { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Passing
{
    [Key]
    public int PassingId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a many to many relation here. What intermediate table does EF build? Also, I don't see why the information on `Bib` is relevant here.

Comment: Bib is the source of the association. The Person property on Tag should get the Person with the same bib (or null), and the Passings property on Person should get a list of Tags with the same bib.  It may be that this isn't possible elegantly with EF, but I am hoping it is so I don't need a messy workaround.

Answer (score 1):

IT IS necessary, when you have a * to * multiplicity into a table, it automaticly creates another table that links these, elseway you cannot put an infinite and variable number of foraign key in one of your table

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework uses [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) to represent database relationships. If you don't want an additional table, what you have here is not a database relationship since keys aren't involved.

You should be able to use some kind of function (or extension function) to get what you want:

```
IQueryable<Passing> PersonPassings(YourContext db, Person p)
{
    return db.Passings.Where(pa => pa.Tag.Bib == p.Bib);
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to create a proper relationship, you'll need an intermediate `Bibs` table to connect `Person` and `Tag`.